# What are difference between referencing a DAO Recordset field?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am curious what are the differences between the following and if there are advantages for one over the other.

Assume MS Access and DAO Recordset

```
rst![field]
rst.Fields("field")
```

Comment: With `rst.[field]`, Access complains *"Method or data member not found"*.

Comment: @Hansup you are correct, that was my mistake. However, one can do the dot method with controls on a form such as me.ctrName.value

Comment: With a form, sure.  But this question is about a `DAO.Recordset`.

Comment: One reason I have used `rst.Fields("field")` a few times is whenever I want to create a function that will be given a field as a string.  Makes it easy to use like: `rs.Fields(strReturnColumn)` honestly that might be possible the other way too though, I just feel like that is clean.  Also the other way you could access a recordset is just `rst!field`.  I generally only square braces when there is a space in the field name like this: `rst![Field Name]`, otherwise Access will complain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rst![field]` refers to an item named *field* in the recordset's default collection.  The `Fields` collection is the recordset's default collection.  So `!` allows you to reference the field without explicitly saying you want a `Field`.

From what I've read in the past, `!` reference is the fastest way to access a collection member.  I'm not really sure about the magnitude of the performance impact; I use `!` because it's more concise (compared to `rst.Fields("field")`).

And if you will be accessing more than one of the recordset fields, consider a `With` block:

```vb
With rst
    Debug.Print !ID.Value
    Debug.Print !Last_Name.Value
End With
```

Supposedly that can be even faster because Access doesn't have to start from `rst` again each time to get to the target field.  Again I'm unsure how much performance improvement that offers; I like it when it makes code more concise.

`rst.Fields(<field name>)` is useful when you don't know the field name ahead of time.  In those cases, use a string variable to hold the field name and feed that variable to `rst.Fields`.  But I don't see any benefit with `rst.Fields` and a hard-coded field name.  That's just more typing for no gain.

As a side point, consider what `rst![field]` actually gives you.  Generally you want `.Value`, which is the field's default property, so you don't need to explicitly ask for `.Value` in those situations.  However in a situation like adding a recordset field to a VBA Collection, the actual field *object* rather than its `.Value` gets added to the collection.  That can be an unwelcome surprise!  [Gord Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2144390/gord-thompson) convinced me to always include `.Value` when I want `.Value`, so that's what I try to do.

Comment: the issue about the field being added to a collection rather than its value has already bitten me. I was able to figure it out but like you said it was an unwelcome surprise.